# How to set values of object array

Tags: c#

Hi I have this code not sure how I can set the value of Value and Value1

```
public class testclass {
   public ID[] test { get; set; }
        public class ID
        {
            [JsonPropertyName("ID")]
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string Value1 { get; set; }
        }
   }

e.g. var a = new testclass ();
a.test = ????
```

Comment: Not following.  You have a class called `ID` with two properties (`Value` and `Value1` - though `Value` is renamed `ID` if you are working with JSON).  Then you have some stray code that declares a property called `test` of type _array of `ID`_.  It's not associated with anything right now and won't compile.  You don't show a class called `testclass` anywhere, so `e.g. var a = new testclass ();` won't come close to compiling.  Showing code that compiles is much more useful if you want meaningful feedback.  Oh, and  you have a stray closing curly bracket (`}`) there as well

Comment: @Flydog57 the code compiles.. i missed adding  testclass while editing code here.. but i am just not sure how i can set random values to value and value1.. this is for testing

Comment: Something like: `a.test = new testclass.ID[] { new testclass.ID() { Value = "test", Value1 = "test1" } };`?  Note that you have defined ID _inside_ testclass, so you can't just do `new ID`.  Plus the `test` property is an array, hence you have to insert a new instance of ID into an array initialization (as @Flydog57 said).

Comment: Well, you create a new instance of `testclass` named `test`.  It has one property, `test` (an array of `ID`, but that's never instantiated).  So, you could say `var a = new testclass(); a.test = new ID[1]; a.test[0].Value = "hello"; a.test[0].Value1 = "world";`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```cs
    var a = new testclass ();
    a.test = new testclass.ID[]{};
```

You can also use object initialization like this:

```cs
    a.test = new testclass.ID[]{
        new testclass.ID(){Value = "1", Value1 = "2"},
        new testclass.ID(){Value = "AnotherValue", Value1 = "10"}
    };
```

And to read individual values:

```
a.test[0].Value == "1"
a.test[1].Value1 == "10"
```

Though these kind of nested classes are not recommended for most cases, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way with your existing code is:

```
a.test = new testclass.ID[] { new testclass.ID() { Value = "test", Value1 = "test1" } };
```

But some refactoring might help you a bit.  Here's a fully compiling example.

Constructors were added to make the syntax cleaner.  Rather than using the syntax of `new ID { Value = "", Value1 = "" };` you can use `new ID("", "");`.  Note that since you're doing serialization/deserialization, you may need to explicitly include a parameterless constructor, as it's unclear from your small code sample how this might get handled.

And the `ID` class was separated out, no longer 'underneath' the `testclass` class.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization; // from System.Text.Json library

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var id = new ID("hello", "world");
            var a = new testclass(id);
        }
    }

    public class testclass
    {
        public ID[] test { get; set; }

        public testclass() { /* might need parameterless for serialization */ }
        
        // just makes an array with one entry
        public testclass(ID id)
        {
            test = new ID[] { id };
        }
    }

    // separate ID class from 'testclass'
    public class ID
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("ID")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Value1 { get; set; }

        public ID() { /* might need parameterless for serialization */ }

        public ID(string value, string value1)
        {
            Value = value;
            Value1 = value1;
        }
    }
}
```